# Querying optional local fields by graphql

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

With GraphQL, I like to query an entire array with all the fields that are found in only some of the array elements.

Assume I have the following data and local client:

```
// data1.json
[
  {
    "type": "title",
    "description": "Title!"
  },
  {
    "type": "person",
    "description": "He has been working in this office for 10 years."
    "name": "Thomas"
    "age": "35"
  },
  {
    "type": "office",
    "description": "Engineering"
    "size": "90"
    "budget": "1500000"
  },
]
```

```js
import data1 from './data1.json'
import data2 from './data2.json' // same structure to data1
... // other imports

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

client.cache.writeData({
  data: {
    departments: [
      {
        name: 'departmentOne',
        data: data1.map(item => ({ ...item, __typename: 'element' })),
        __typename: 'department'
      },
      {
        name: 'departmentTwo',
        data: data2.map(item => ({ ...item, __typename: 'element' })),
        __typename: 'department'
      }
    ],
    __typename: 'departments'
  }
});
```

Then, in one of my component, how do I get all the elements in the departments?

When I query this it just works:

```
{
  departments @client {
    name
    data {
      type
      description
      __typename
    }
    __typename
  }
}
```

But the following query will return nothing:

```
{
  departments @client {
    name
    data {
      type
      description
      name
      age
      size
      budget
      __typename
    }
    __typename
  }
}
```

I suppose I need to add a local resolver or typeDefs for this purpose, but how would it look like?

In the first place, I am not sure if the cache has all the array. As some of the fields (i.e., "name", "age", and others) are missing in some element, might it omit the data automatically?